# PHP: Get Values of all <options> Tag to an array

Tags: php, xpath, preg-match

First of all: Sorry, I´m just learning coding, so this might be an easy question :).

What I want to archive is getting the values of all

```
<option value="123"></option>
<option value="412"></option>
```

in an html document into an array. So for the above example only the "123" "412" etc. The arrays then will get checked if they are only numbers.

This is what i got:

```
$html = file_get_contents(url);
preg_match_all('/value="(\w+)"/', $html, $result);
var_dump($result);
$digits = array_filter($result, 'ctype_digit');
```

What I get from this is nothing, because the $result gives me results like:

```
value="123"
```

I do know that I messed up with those regular expressions, but I cant´t get ir right.

And then I´m not sure whether it is better to use XPath to select it, but I did not get that either :(.

Any help is highly appreciated! :)

Comment: If it's an HTML form ... why not just post the values to the server?

Comment: You could probably use `DomDocument()` http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Comment: @CD001 It´s a remote Server. I´m trying to build a script for easy handling some actions here. The values will get used for something else. So it´s just about analysing the HTML File and get the values to work with them afterwards. Or did I get your question wrong?

Comment: @itxsys - nah, you understood my question correctly, just what you're doing seems really *weird* to me... but as stated above, `DOMDocument` is your best bet to parse an HTML document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice would be to not use a regex but a domparser.

For your provided data, the `$result` is an `array` which contains 2 arrays. Your values are in the second array `$result[1]`

You could update your code to:

```
preg_match_all('/value="(\w+)/', $html, $result);
$digits = array_filter($result[1], 'ctype_digit');
var_dump($digits);
```

That would give you:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "123"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "412"
}
```

[Php demo output](https://3v4l.org/mMbO0)

An alternative regex:

[`value="\K\d+(?=")`](https://regex101.com/r/ZFdXNs/1) which would match one or more digits `d+`

[Php demo output](https://3v4l.org/XR75H)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the hint by CD001 and Kisaragi I manged it. It´s pretty simple with the DOMDocument thing...sometimes one just thinks too complicated... .

```
$html = file_get_contents('url');
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$options = $dom->getElementsByTagName('option');
$digits = array();
foreach ($options as $option) {
    $valueID = $option->getAttribute('value');
    array_push($digits, $valueID);
}
var_dump($digits);
```